# Migrating from apache to nginx

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx

So I've been using apache for all of my PHP projects, but now I've been forced to using nginx on the server. I've no clue how to do pretty urls with nginx. So I started converting my .htaccess file into an nginx config script, and tried modifying the nginx config file, but no luck.

This is my **.htaccess** file:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /wallfly-mvc/public
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This is my **nginx.conf** server block:

```
server {
    listen 80; listen [::]:80;
    server_name  deco3801-superflyz.uqcloud.net;
    root         /var/www/htdocs;

    include "set_cookie.conf";
    rewrite_by_lua_file "etc/nginx/lua/auth_filter.lua";

    location / {
        index  index.html index.htm index.php index.jsp index.aspx;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /wallfly-mvc/public/ {
        if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/wallfly-mvc/public/(.+)$ /wallfly-mvc/public/index.php?url=$1 break;
        }
    }
}
```

I want every request to point to **public/index.php**. This is my **project structure**:

```
wallfly-mvc/
  app/
  public/
    index.php
    css/
    js/
    img/
```

How should I change the nginx.conf file? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you should change root in config : like root         /wallfly-mvc/public;

Answer (score 0):

You can use `location ^~` to capture the directory. Its priority is higher `location /`

```
server {
    #...

    location ^~ /wallfly-mvc/public/ {
        if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/wallfly-mvc/public/(.+)$ /wallfly-mvc/public/index.php?url=$1 break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `location /wallfly-mvc/public` has higher priority than `location /` - because `/wallfly-mvc/public` is the longest match (see here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location )

Comment: Yeah, my mistake.  So my solution is wrong. and it needs rewrite in the `location /` before try_files